# How do I add Material Output node when it does not show up automatically?

Tags: node-editor

I'm in Cycles, with 'Use Nodes' selected and the basic node Material Output did not show up. How can I add Material Output it when it's not a menu option?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The node editor works with three different types of nodes.

[image]

By default the node editor is configured for compositing [image].

Change to the Material node editor [image]:

[image]

More info:

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/introduction.html#node-tree-types

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/editor.html

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. Thanks :)

Comment: It's a common mistake.