# Why is the node editor showing different kinds of nodes?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been following [this](https://youtu.be/2I6xmgLBeA4?t=7m46s) tutorial until I started adding nodes. The problem is that he has completely different nodes than I have. Even nodes that are created at start are different (I have Material and Output and he has Render Layers and Composite).
Have I missed something or should I use different nodes than he?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50860/how-do-i-add-material-output-node-when-it-does-not-show-up-automatically/50861#50861

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is was for older versions (2.79 and previous)

**For blender version 2.8x [read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192447/92768)**

---

Without any addons, the Node Editor can be used in three different modes:
[image: node editor header]

You are looking at the cycles material (shader) nodes. The tutorial is using the compositor nodes.

Simply click on the *Compositing* button in the Node Editor header to switch to the compositor nodes.
[image: compositor nodes]

Also make sure the *Use nodes* box is checked.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in other answers, if you are seeing different nodes than what you expect, then you are using the wrong editor.

As of 2.8+ versions of Blender, with the new workflow oriented paradigm, the old generic "Node Editor" is no more.

Along with other editors it has been split into several different specific task-oriented editors.

- The *Shader Editor* for editing Cycles and EEVEE materials,
  including shaders and textures
- The *Texture Editor* for legacy node based textures for World, Brushes, Modifiers, and Line Styles.
- *Geomery Nodes* for parametric construction and procedural modelling
- The *Compositor* for post-production and composition of your renders.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're in the material node editor currently. The tutorial is about compositing. Switch to the compositor by checking this button:

[image: compositor]