# Where is the Viewer node?

Tags: node-editor

Where is the Viewer node located at? Blender manual says it is an Output node but it is not under output.
I have blender 2.77.

Regards,
Koreenium

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/why-is-the-node-editor-showing-different-kinds-of-nodes/61015#61015

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Blender Manual is right. There is a [viewer node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/viewer.html#viewer-node) under Output, but it's in the Composite Node Editor. I bet you are looking in the Material Node Editor.

To get one in the Material Node Editor, you have to activate the [Node Wrangler add-on](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html?#node-wrangler), then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to create a [temporary Viewer Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html?#shader-viewer).