# Add background image to render

Tags: rendering

I have a blender project that renders a transparent background. I would like to add a background image when rendering.

I tried following [this guide](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background/) except for the part where they explain about the shadow. But my background image is not rendered.

I think the problem is in the Node Editor (where I cannot make a configuration like the one in the guide). This is what I did:

- Added a background image
  [image]
- Switched to Node Editor following he guide instructions. But my Node Editor screen looks empty like this:
  [image]

Can you help me obtain a background image on the final render?

Comment: In order to overlay any image over / behind a render you want to use compositing nodes, not material. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/why-is-the-node-editor-showing-different-kinds-of-nodes

Comment: maybe this help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h--yT0d28XA

Comment: Basically you have to switch the *Node Editor* to *Compositing Mode* not materials as it currently is in your screenshot.