# UV texture Nodes

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, node-editor

I have been facing an issue for several days, and having tried most of the recommendations out there I wanted your help

The UV texture I use on a mesh plane does not appear in my renders, even though the material and texture seem to be applied correctly

I have been trying to debug the problem in the render layers and the node editor without any luck

Configuration
Blender Render
Blender 2.79

[image]

[image]

Please find attached my blend file 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Km_nCSI0qQM94q5GTPjQGMcFEjtntpY_/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance!
Stefanos C.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/why-is-the-node-editor-showing-different-kinds-of-nodes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should disable use node of IMG_7930_b.jpg.000 and increase world mist start amount https://youtu.be/F1y6CmgN1nU

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - This has resolved the problem!