# In the Shader Editor Add>Converter>Combine/Separate RGBA is not available

Tags: node-editor

Blender 2.8 Manual at:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/shader_nodes/converter/combine_separate.html
shows that the combine/separate shader nodes uses RGBA and not just RGB

my install of Blender 2.8 only allows for combine/separate of RGB. Did I miss something? or do I need to hit some checkbox somewhere? or what?

**BLENDER MANUAL**

```
=====================
```

[image: Snipped from Blender 2.8 Manual]

```
=====================
```

**MY INSTALL**

```
=====================
```

[image: Snipped from my Blender 2.8 install]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61013/why-is-the-node-editor-showing-different-kinds-of-nodes

Comment: Compositor nodes, though the documentation seems to be incorrect.

Comment: The documentation now states -- In the texture context only RGB color space is available.