# Can't find the Alpha Over Node

Tags: node-editor

I'm using Blender 2.77 and i can't find the Alpha Over Node. 
I'm getting crazy.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What mode is the compositor window in (i.e. are you working on a material, global background, output composite, etc)? A screen shot would help determine that.

Comment: I'm working in a material for a object. I'm trying to use a .tga file as a texture, and i need to use another .tga that is the alpha using the alpha over node.

Comment: i checked what you send me but everything is good. I'm in cycles render and i'm using already the nodes, but the Alpha Over Node is not in the list of nodes available

Comment: @MadFamily the alpha over node is a compositing node not a material node. The Node editor has several modes. Make sure you are using the correct one

Comment: see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53338/1853

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50860/how-do-i-add-material-output-node-when-it-does-not-show-up-automatically/50861#50861