# Why do I have no 'Shader' category when trying to add nodes?

Tags: materials, shaders

I am a complete beginner. So, I might be dumb - sorry!

I made a 3D model. Now, I want to work on its surface - which lead me to materials and shaders. So, I added a material and then opened the Node Editor. I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a shader and I got the following:

[image]

There is no Shader in the list. So, could you please tell me how to get it?

The Blender version I am using is 2.79b

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50860/how-do-i-add-material-output-node-when-it-does-not-show-up-automatically/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are using cycles.

On the info window [image]

select cycles as the render engine

[image]

Then go to the node editor.
Without any addons, the Node Editor can be used in three different modes:

[image: node editor header]

You are looking at the compositor nodes.

Click on the *materials* button in the Node Editor header.

Also make sure the *Use nodes* box is checked.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are attempting to follow a Cycles tutorial, but you are using Blender Render.

In the Info editor (the bar at the very top), choose Cycles Render instead of Blender Render.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using the Blender Renderer.